# How do I get from the basic Helmholtz equation to this parametrised form?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-electrodynamics

So I am reading this paper which says that the following equation arises when projecting the Helmholtz equation for electromagnetic field E with wavenumber k in the forward direction z.

$$i\partial_zE+(\sqrt{\nabla^2+k^2})E=0.$$

I know the Helmholtz equation which is $$\nabla^2A+k^2A=0$$ how do I get from here to that parametrised form? 
A follow up question would be that the paper says this equation describes light propagation beyond paraxial approximation. I know that paraxial approximation is when we consider rays of light going very close to the principle axis. How does that apply here?

EDIT: The paper I mention here is 'Quantum gravity simulation by non-paraxial nonlinear optics' by Claudio Conti, [*Phys. Rev. A* **89**, 061801(R) (2014)](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevA.89.061801), [arXiv:1406.6677](https://arxiv.org/abs/1406.6677).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting from the wave equation for the electric field:
$$\left(\nabla^2 - \frac{1}{c^2} \frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}\right)\textbf{E} =0$$
You can separate variables into spatial variables and $t$ to obtain the Helmholtz equation:
$$\left(\nabla^2 +k^2\right)\textbf{E} =0$$
for the spatial-dependent part of the electric field.

Now denoting the "transverse" laplacian as $\nabla_T^2 =\partial_x^2+\partial_y^2 $, one gets:
$$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial z^2}\textbf{E}=-\left(\nabla_T^2 +k^2\right)\textbf{E}$$
Taking a formal square root and rearranging you obtain the equation you're looking for:
$$i\partial_z\textbf{E}+\sqrt{\nabla_T^2 +k^2}\textbf{E}=0$$
I was confused at first because I thought the $\nabla$ in the square root included the $z$ component. The paper you quoted specifies a few lines below the equation that the $\nabla$ is only transverse.